# ssh scp command not working

Tags: ssh

I am using PuTTY to connect my Windows machine with remote machine and I am able to connect to remote machine but when I am using SCP command to download some files to my local Windows machine it is saying:

```
ssh: connect to host XXXXXXXXXX port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I am writing this command:

```
scp * username@mywindowsmachine:~/Desktop
```

Comment: Tip : You should avoid "please reply as soon as possible" and so on in order not to be downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

Use winscp to do this :

http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction

WinSCP will enable you to exchange files with the server while ssh is used to issue shell commands on this server (and is powerless in your case as your local windows machine can't probably answer to its ssh connections).

You would use scp if you were on a shell but as you're on windows (and probably don't use things like cygwin), you'll find winscp to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

if you manage the server you are trying to connect to, start the SSHD with debugging enabled you will see exactly why it is refusing the connection

Comment: he is trying to issue scp commands FROM the server to its windows machine. Hence my answer.

Answer (score 0):

IF sudo chown -R www-data:webmasters/dir/dir/dotfile - possibly need to give permissions to your bash "user" instead via ssh.